# How to solve this system of ODE by series expansion?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, numerical-calculus

I have the following system of ordinary differential equations up to fourth order (one of the equations is like a restriction for the other) for the one variable real functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$:

$0=\frac{-12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t)^2 a''(t)^2-24 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t) a'(t)^2 b''(t)+60 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 a'(t)^2 b'(t)^2-36 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) b(t)^2 a'(t)^4+6 \gamma  a(t)^2 b(t)^4 a'(t)^2+24 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a^{(3)}(t) a(t)^2 b(t)^2 a'(t)-24 b'(t) \left(\gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t) b(t) a'(t)^3+2 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t) a'(t) a''(t)\right)+24 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t) b(t)^2 a'(t)^2 a''(t)-\Lambda  a(t)^4 b(t)^2}{2 \gamma  a(t)^4 b(t)^4}$

$0=-\frac{8 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 a^{(4)}(t) b(t)^3+12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t)^3 a''(t)^2-8 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 b^{(3)}(t) b(t)^2 a'(t)-120 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 a'(t) b'(t)^3+12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) b(t)^3 a'(t)^4+2 \gamma  a(t)^2 b(t)^5 a'(t)^2+16 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 a^{(3)}(t) b(t)^3 a'(t)+60 b'(t)^2 \left(2 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 b(t) a''(t)+\gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t) a'(t)^2\right)-16 b''(t) \left(2 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 b(t)^2 a''(t)-5 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 b(t) a'(t) b'(t)+\gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t)^2 a'(t)^2\right)+4 a''(t) \left(\gamma  a(t)^3 b(t)^5-12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t) b(t)^3 a'(t)^2\right)-4 b'(t) \left(12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^3 a^{(3)}(t) b(t)^2-12 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t) b(t)^2 a'(t)^3+\gamma  a(t)^3 b(t)^4 a'(t)+18 \gamma  (3 \alpha -\beta ) a(t)^2 b(t)^2 a'(t) a''(t)\right)-\Lambda  b(t)^7}{2 \gamma  a(t)^2 b(t)^7}$

Where I am using prime to denote derivative with respect to time $t$.

Here, $\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$ and $\Lambda$ are constants of $O(1)$. Of course, a lot of initial conditions need to be given. Some reasonable initial conditions from the context of the problem are $a(t=1)=b(t=1)=1$, and their first derivatives should be positive $a'(t=1),b'(t=1)>0$ but not so big (0.5, for example). I don't have more information in order to give solid initial conditions for the higher derivatives, but it is reasonable again to choose them positive and the initial condition for the second derivative $b''(t=1)$ can be obtained from the first equation by consistency. One could choose, for example:
$
a(1) = 1, a'(1) = 1, a''(1) = 1/2, a'''(1) =1/2 , b(1) = 1, 
 b'(1) = 1, b''(1) = -(103/24)
$

I would like to know if it's possible to know something about the approximate solution of this system, for example expanding $a(t)=\sum_k^n a_kt^k$ and $b(t)=\sum_k^n b_kt^k$.

Comment: Is there also a background to the equation, like the description of a physical phenomenon or where does the equation come from?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve it and do you really want to have a solution by substituting series expansions, or do you use other numerical methods, because the ones you mentioned will take forever to solve?

Comment: @KevinDietrich Yes, there's a physical background. But the physical background symmetries/properties are all already used, so it won't help. At the moment I have tried optimization procedure via the Euler wavelets method as you can see in this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286505/solving-a-system-of-two-coupled-ordinary-differential-equations-up-to-fourth-ord/286594?noredirect=1#comment713790_286594, but I'm not sure if this is correct since it lacks uniqueness and the method is kinda obscure for me